# Concatenation of foldername and filenames in nmake

Tags: makefile, nmake

I have a Makefile for Nmake containing a list of files in a macro:

```
MYSRCFILES1=myfolder\file1.svg myfolder\file2.svg ... myfolder\file99.svg
```

and a second one just like this:

```
MYSRCFILES2=myfolder2\file1.svg myfolder2\file2.svg ... myfolder2\file99.svg
```

What I am trying is to avoid duplication of the list of files, and to avoid duplication of the folder names, something like this:

```
MYSRCFILES0=file1.svg file2.svg file3.svg

MYSRCFILES1="prepend 'myfolder\' to each element of $(MYSRCFILES0)"

MYSRCFILES2="prepend 'myfolder2\' to each element of $(MYSRCFILES0)"
```

Digging myself through the documentation of Nmake I haven't found a solution so far. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found a solution for my problem, it's not perfect since I have to add a `.\` to every file but that seems to be ok in my case:

```
 MYSRCFILES0=.\file1.svg .\file2.svg .\file3.svg ...

 MYSRCFILES1=$(MYSRCFILES0:.\=myfolder\)

 MYSRCFILES2=$(MYSRCFILES0:.\=myfolder2\)
```

does the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Is Nmake simillar to make? You can use patsubst ("pattern substitute string") function like this:

```
MYSRCFILES0=.\file1.svg .\file2.svg .\file3.svg ...
MYSRCFILES1=$(patsubst %,myFolder/%,MYSRCFILES0)
MYSRCFILES2=$(patsubst %,myFolder2/%,MYSRCFILES0)
```

Comment: No, this won't work in Nmake. My own solution does the same thing, but in NMake syntax. If one uses Unix make (or is this GNU-make specific?), then perhaps your solution will be appropriate, but that was not what I was looking for.